# PHPStorm code completion for magic invoke static methods (Using curly braces syntax) [Pendent]

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Using the following code, the code completion works fine!

```
class FooClass
{
    public function run(){}
}

/**
 * @method static FooClass foo(bool $param1 = false)
 */

class Test
{
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        //Implementation code ..
    }
}

//Code completes fine for FooClass methods ..
Test::foo()->run();
```

But, its possible to IDE (PhpStorm) complete the code using the following php invocation method write style (Curly braces)?

```
//Code NOT completes fine ..
Test::{"foo"}();
```

If so, how? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Whats your PHP version?

Comment: PHP: 7.1.0 and PHPStorm: 2017.1.4

Comment: Shouldn't be `Test::{"foo"}()->run();` ?

Comment: If i write Test::{"foo"}()->run(); yes it works .. But the discussion is about the code completion provided by the IDE. In first example works, the IDE shows ->run() or otherwise FooClass methods, but using Test::{"foo"}(); none method completion is showed ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpStorm doesn't support dynamic fields/methods. For a static tool, it's hard to track which field/method is actually accessed. Let's take a look at a more realistic example.

```
function foo($str) {
    //Code NOT completes fine ..
    Test::{$str}()->run();
}
```

This is how the dynamic invocation usually looks like. In a real code, `$str` is typically a combination of an external input (e.g. from a database) and business logic. Both are beyond the possibilities of a static analysis.